# Default Filename for no answer

Tags: java

So i have a program that creates a new file but need it to have a default file name if the user was to not enter anything, and was wondering if anyone could help with it.

So far i have the program asking the user for the file name but not sure what to do to set the default to for say "output.txt".

Here is a snip-it of my code:

```
 //Creates a Scanner Object for keyboard input.
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

 //Get the filename.
 System.out.print("Enter a filename: ");
 filename = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to test if the string is empty, which can be done with [`String#isEmpty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()) in conjuction with [`String#trim`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()), from the documentation:

> **`isEmpty`**
>
> `public boolean isEmpty()`
>
> Returns true if, and only if, `length()` is 0.

That means, once we trim to remove whitespace, we can test if length is 0.  Thus, any inputs that consist of just spaces will not be used as filenames, and will default, else it will used the given. You can apply this like so:

```
File file = new File(filename.trim().isEmpty() ? "output.txt" : filename);
    
try {       
    file.createNewFile();
} catch(IOException ex) {
    //file was not created successfully
}
```

This will create a new `File` object, which will have a filename based on if the user inputted anything (whitespace excluded). `file.createNewFile()` will just create the file if it does not exist.

Comment: How would this collect the user imput tho, were would the scanner be users before?

Comment: @AndrewLi I figured it out, thanks. just had to make it work with the rest of my code.

Answer (score 3):

Test what the user has entered as a filename.  If it is an empty string, use the default filename.

You may want to "trim" the string too.  A filename with leading or trailing whitespace characters would be a bad idea.

Comment: Could you explain how to do that?

Comment: What is to explain?  These are all Java 101 tasks.  And if you need to know how to do them, then you should **consult the javadocs** (for `java.lang.String`) because the API provides standard methods for doing them.  (And, in the process of looking,  you will probably discover other useful methods in the String API that you can use in other contexts.)

Comment: Thanks, as a newbie to java i'll defiantly take a look.

Comment: *"..  i'll defiantly take a look"*  - Why am I reminded of the Mony Python Black Knight sketch? :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's sure you need some condition for achieve this.

Perhaps, you probably need simple method like this:

```
isNotNullOrEmpty(filename) ? filename : defaultFileName;

    private static boolean isNotNullOrEmpty(String str) {
        return str != null && !str.isEmpty();
    }
```